# What to Import from WSP to build Web Template solution in Visual Studio?

Tags: 2010, visual-studio-2012, web-template

I'm trying to create a custom web template for SharePoint 2010.  The client has already configured a prototype web site in SharePoint, which is essentially a standard blog site, with some modifications.  The changes include:

- edits to several list form pages (for example, hiding some objects inside security trimmed controls and pointing some forms to a custom master page)
- adding one or more new master pages just for these sites

When I save the site as a template, and then import the WSP file into Visual Studio 2012, I'm asked which components to import.  I only want the bare minimum imported - which items would they be?  I suspect the "Web Template" is required, but would anything else be needed based on the changes I've mentioned?

Thanks kindly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you select the Web Template only, Visual Studio will most likely suggest that you import everything else that is required anyway.  When prompted, ensure you say "Yes" to importing those dependencies.